# Trying to use ffi in Electron is fatal erroring

Tags: node.js, electron, node-ffi

I installed `ffi` with `npm install ffi --save-dev` I then use it in my electron app like this:

```
const {app, Menu, Tray, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')
const ffi = require('ffi');
console.log('ffi:', ffi);
```

but it throws this error, image -

Image typed out:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\UserS\MercuriuS\DocumentS\GitHub\NativeShot\src\e|ectror\\nodeimo...\binding.node
at Error (native)
at process.rnodule.(anonyrnous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
at object.Module.,extensions..node (rnodule.js:583:18)
at object.rnodule.(anonyrnous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
at Moduleload (rnodule.js:473:32)
at tryModuIeLoad (rnodule.js:432:12)
at FunctionModuleJoad (rnodule.js:424:3)
at Modulerequire (rnodule.js:483:17)
at require (internal/modulejs:20:19)
at bindings
(C:\UserS\MercuriuS\DocumentS\GitHub\NativeShot\src\e|ectron\nodeimodules\binding...:44)
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

I am on windows so i even tried - https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

But this doesn't fix it.

Comment: Hello! Did you manage to install and run ffi in Electron container?

Comment: Hi @VolodymyrBezuglyy I am still struggling with it :( If you figure out may you please write it out step by step :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebuild `ffi` for your Electron version using one of the [documented approaches](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/). An easier alternative might be to use [`electron-forge`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge) which I believe takes care of rebuilding native modules for you.

Comment: Thanks Vadim! I'll read those docs and report the steps I took here.

Comment: If you're using Webpack, you also have to add ffi/ref as "externals", as I found out here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17745#issuecomment-511115877